# How to properly configure caching for unit testing in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, caching

I am using Zend_Cache_Manager in one of my controllers to detect and drop (via 304 response) multiple request from the same source within a minute.

**The problem is that with caching turned on, my controller unit tests are failing**.

Should I change the backend to Zend_Cache_Backend_Blackhole or Zend_Cache_Backend_Test, or should I clear the cache in the tests setUp()? Are there other appropriate options?

Comment: For reference, I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your configuration to disable cache manager for the test environment, eg

```
[test : production]
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.options.caching = false
```

Make sure your env is set to `test` for testing

Comment: Thanks! If I ever want to write specific unit tests for the caching can I call $cache->setOption('caching', true) in the test's setUp()?